# How to use Spannable String Builder to enclose string within h1 tag

Tags: android

How can i set a particular string as a title in Edittext. I want to output to look like something like this:

> ## Title
>
> Some other text.

I have tried to make the text bold and give it a larger style. Something like this:

```
s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, length ,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 0, length , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

That does the trick but i wish if i could instead create a **h1** tag around the string so the formatted html code i extract from Edittext can be displayed in textview or used elsewhere.

### Update

It seems like a problem with Html class. Try something like this.

```
Log.d("Test", Html.toHtml(Html.fromHtml("<h1>Hello</h1>")));
```

You would get something like this in your logs:

```
<p dir="ltr"><b>Hello</b></p>
```

It seems like Html class is capable of converting *h1* tags to spannable but not capable of being able to convert it back to *h1* tags.

The *fromHtml* method converts the header tags to Spannable using a similar trick i already stated above. It's not implemented in the *toHtml* method and hence it don't create header tags from Spannable. Can someone try to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [`HTML.fromHtml(String text)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))

This will parse HTML and return a spanned string. The only thing notable is, that it's a bit tricky modifying the styles used for the spans.

Comment: Am actually dynamically changing the contents. I am calling this from a TextWatcher

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Which worked for me

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(<h1>Your content</h1>));
```